# how can i load an external html and make it work with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, dom

I want to load an external html to my actual html with `load` but not triggered by `click`. I want to load it on page on document `ready` event. I did like this but the jquery doesn't apply to the loaded content.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 

     $( "#rezervations" ).load("http://websoftit.ro/wayoutz/calendar.php");

});
</script>
```

I mean content is loaded but the jquery from the main doc doesn't work for the loaded content. Example for script that should work on loaded content

```
<script>
 $(".table").on("click", "td", function() {
     $(this).closest("tr").siblings().removeClass("td_select");
    $(this).toggleClass("td_select");
   });

</script>
```

Comment: Works fine **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/d3umm7w8/)**. whats the problem??

Comment: it loads it but the jquery scripts not working for loaded content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok then you might need to write it as below:

```
$( "#rezervations" ).load("http://websoftit.ro/wayoutz/calendar.php",function(){
       $(".table").on("click", "td", function() {      
             $(this).closest("tr").siblings().removeClass("td_select"); 
             $(this).toggleClass("td_select"); 
       });
     //Your other initialization here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i have checked it and there is not problem with your code its working fine just check that you have particular div with id rezervations.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $( "#rezervations" ).load("http://websoftit.ro/wayoutz/calendar.php");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rezervations">HELLO</div>
```

Regards

Comment: it works, it loads the content but the jquery scripts not working for it. For example this should work for loaded content:`<script>
 $(".table").on("click", "td", function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").siblings().removeClass("td_select");
    $(this).toggleClass("td_select");
   });
   
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

Example loading a header:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
$("header").load("http://localhost/js/header.html", function() {
    $('body').trigger('headerReady');
});
});
```

From the api: https://api.jquery.com/trigger/  , then

```
$('body').on('headerReady', function(){
//do ur stuff here 
});
```